# New project proposal to different companies

Tags: negotiation, projects

I proposed a business development to three IT companies from my state during the last months without any answers. Suddenly, in a single week, all of them are interested in talking with me to learn more about the project. Any case would need me to move from home and quit my current position.

**How should I proceed?**

Answer all of them and discover if they are finally interested and what they offer to me?

OR

Negotiate one by one?

I am scared of all of them developing the idea finally and discovering I was talking with the three of them at the same time.

Comment: It’s quite possible that you are close to the end of a tax year, and people in three companies found they had leftover budget and either spend it or lose it. So all three at the same time is not unexpected.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @gnasher729 , it seems really reasonable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Answer all of them and discover if they are finally interested and what they offer to me?

Yes

> I am scared of all of them ... discovering I was talking with the three of them at the same time

Nothing to be scared about. Unless you promised exclusivity, that's perfectly normal and expected.

Comment: Thanks for the simplicity in your answer. Exclusivity is not over the board. I am keeping conversations with all of them and providing little info pills. So far, so good. Let's see what happens...

Answer (score 4):

So you put out a tender and got 3 responses.
It's quite normal for those to take a while if the responders are serious and want to determine first if they will have the resources available to take on the work.

Enter initial talks with all three, disclose that there are other potential partners without mentioning who they are, and without starting a bidding war between them, and see which offer best matches your needs.

You might even end up with a combined team from 2 or all 3 of them, especially if it's a very large project.

Comment: The bidding idea is difficult to be carried out, because both of them would be able to find an alternative once I told them some details. The combined team is even less possible as the companies compete in the same field. Anyway, the global idea yo go for all was the key. Thank you!